# ASP.NET Core 2.2 All AJAX POST Calls Returns 404 When Page is in iFrame

Tags: asp.net, iframe, http-status-code-404

When I make a simple AJAX Submit call from a form on an ASP.NET 2.2 website which is hosted as an iFrame inside other website, it always returns 404.

When I make the same call but the website is not inside the iFrame, everything works fine.

This is the AJAX call I am using. PS: I hardcoded the URL to avoid any routing issues.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#saveConfiguration').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

                var form = $(this).closest('form');
                var url = "https://server/api/external/helloworld";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                        alert(xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });


            });
        });
```

This is the API method I am calling:

```
        [HttpPost("HelloWorld")]
        public IEnumerable<string> HelloWorld()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

I also whitelisted the master domain from CORS in the Startup.cs file. It doesn't help.

Plus added Suppress X Frame Options:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);
```

Did anyone encounter this scenario? Again, this happens only when the website is hosted as an iFrame. When the website is hosted as master, it doesn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I later found out the reason why this is happening.

This is not related to any specifics of ASP.NET Core. This is caused by a third-party Atlassian library that I am using which is taking control over AJAX calls and makes them relative to Atlassian domain: